# Windows Application ignores app.config and uses something to connect to local database

Tags: vb.net, app-config

The application sits on a virtual environment and when I remote in and run the application, it connects to the remote database.  However, when I remote in with a service account and double click the same .exe, it tries to connect to the local host database and ignores the app.config. The code is the same, only the login name I use is different.  The login I use is part of the local admin group.  Any ideas?

Comment: Your question is specifically about app.config. You don't have to include every tag that might possibly contain part of the word 'configuration' in it. :) Can you be more specific about "a service account" and what you're using to "remote in"?

Comment: Remote Desktop Connection to a virtual PC, that has Windows 2008 on it.  The service account is just a domain account, that has been added to the local administrator group.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't indicated whether or not this is the case in your question, but my first suspicion is that you are storing the connection strings in settings, but the connection string has been marked as a user-specific setting.

Comment: Yes, that could be it. I am storing it in the settings. In fact, I actually took over the application. I will have a look at this and let you know.

Comment: It turns out this helped. The user setting was stored in the application data for the user.

Answer (score 0):

In the logic of the code it was doing a comparison of the SQL server setting in the config (Settings), which was entered in lower case, against the list of SQL servers (all in upper case).  Since it couldn't find any match, the datasource was blank [datasource=;],hence causing the code to look local.  My fix was to use String.Compare and ignore the case, which created the match and I was able to connect to the remote SQL server.